# Constructing simply connected domains, starting from disks

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $\mathcal{G} $ be the collection of nonempty, open, connected subsets of $\mathbb{C} $. For each $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{G} $, we may ask whether $\mathcal{S} $ is 'closed' under the following two 'operations'.

1. If $D_1, D_2\in\mathcal{S} $ and $D_1\cap D_2 $ is nonempty and connected, then $D_1\cup D_2\in\mathcal{S} $.
2. If $D_1, D_2, D_3,\ldots\in\mathcal{S} $ and $D_n\subset D_{n+1} $ for all $n=1,2, 3,\ldots $, then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n\in\mathcal{S} $.

In page 87 of *Complex Analysis* by Freitag and Busam, the authors remark that the following can be proven in a non-trvial way:

> If $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{G} $ contains all (nonempty open) disks and is closed under the above two operations, then $\mathcal{S} $ contains all simply connected domains in $\mathbb{C} $

So, how do we prove this statement? Can we generalize this to higher dimensions?

Comment: Just an idea: Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and simply connected. For each $x\in X$, let $ \epsilon = \epsilon_x > 0$ be the biggest $\epsilon$ such that the open ball $B(x, \epsilon_x)$ is contained in $X$. Fix $y\in X$. Let $D_1 = B(y, \epsilon_y)$ and inductively let $D_{n+1}=\cup_{x\in D_n} B(x, \epsilon_x)$. Argue that $\cup_n D_n = X$.

Comment: @JeffreyM But the union $\bigcup_{x\in D_n}$ is uncountable and it is not linearly ordered.

Comment: True. One way to rectify this: Take $D_1 = B(y, \epsilon_y)$ as before. Now inductively let $\{x^n_1, x^n_2, ...\} \subseteq D_n$ be a countable dense (in $D_n$) set. Let $P_1^{n+1} = D_n \cup B(x^n_1, \epsilon_{x^n_1})$, and inductively let $P_{i+1}^{n+1}= P_i^{n+1} \cup B(x^n_{i+1}, \epsilon_{x^n_{i+1}})$. Finally, let $D_{n+1} = \cup_i P^{n+1}_i$. As before, argue that $\cup_n D_n = X$.

Comment: One problem with my idea is that it doesn't use the simply connectedness of $X$ at all. In fact, it should work for any connected set, which is a much stronger conclusion. So I assume I am making a mistake somewhere along the way.

Comment: Also what definition of simply connected are you using? There is the standard definition in terms of the fundamental group, but some authors define a subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to be simply connected iff $\hat{\mathbb{C}} - X$ is connected (where $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ denotes the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$, aka the "Riemann sphere", aka the "extended complex plane").

Comment: @JeffreyM A space is simply connected iff it is path-connected and has a trivial fundamental group. But I don't think the definition really matters here since we are already familiar with the Riemann mapping theorem and its equivalents. Also, your construction of $P_{i+1}^2$ from $P_{i}^2$ can be troublesome when the 'geometry' of $P_{i}^2$ is so complicated that the intersection of $P_{i}^2$ with a disk has several connected components.

Comment: Ah yes good catch. My apologies for the many comments. I am just brainstorming a bit.

Comment: If you can  use RMT, a suggestion would be first to do it for  bounded simply connected domains with analytic boundary (their boundary is an analytic Jordan curve) which may be easier and then use RMT and write any $\Omega$ simply connected as $\cup_{n}f(D(0, 1-1/n))$ where $f: \mathbb D \to \Omega$ is a Riemann map as all $f(D(0, 1-1/n)$ have analytic boundary and are included one in another

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for the comment. I believe we can then reduce the problem to the case of a polygon, and then a triangle, which looks promising. I wonder whether we can do this in three-dimensional space..

Comment: Have no idea about 3d space - I vaguely remember there are very weird simply connected open sets there - eg horned Alexander sphere and so who knows; 2d is special due to RMT

Comment: Hint: Use the Seifert-van Kampen theorem (dimension does not matter).

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you know the statement of the Seifert-van Kampen theorem? If not, then start by reading it.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I am familiar with van Kampen's theorem, but I don't see how it implies that $\mathcal{S} $ contains all simply connected domains.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike It seems to me that Seifert van Kampen can be used to show that all sets which are constructible from disks by the operations are simply connected, but I cannot see the converse.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Yes, it implies that all the subsets constructed this way are simply connected. The other direction, I think, will be only valid for surfaces.

Comment: For the converse direction, I was thinking of something like this: Let $\Omega $ be a simply connected proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \Omega$ a Riemann map. Consider $\gamma_{r} = f \circ C_r$ where $C_r = \partial \Delta(0,r)$ , $r \in [0,1-\epsilon]$, then $\gamma_{r}$ is a homotopy from the point $f(0)$ to a analytic Jordan curve bounding $\Omega_{\epsilon}$, and we should be able to show that $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$ by basically drawing a bunch of small disks entered at the points of each curve $\gamma_{r}$.Finally let$\epsilon \downarrow 0$.

Comment: Here $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ is the region bounded by $\gamma_{\epsilon}$, the idea is that these regions form a exhausting sequence for $\Omega$, and by property $2$, if we can show each $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$, it also follows that $\Omega$ is in $\mathcal{S}$. The trickier part is showing each $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$, in my head it seems possible to do this by drawing a union of small disks centered at each of the boundaries and taking unions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(z_0,\ldots,z_{n - 1}) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $\gamma : \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the only affine by parts function that is affine on each $\left[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k + 1}{n}\right]$ such that for all $k$, $\gamma\!\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = z_{k\%n}$. If $\gamma$ is injective, it is a Jordan curve and we denote by $[z_0,\ldots,z_{n - 1}]$ its interior which is a polygon with $n$ vertices which are the $z_k$. By Jordan's theorem, such polygons are biholomorphic to the open unit disk $\mathbb{D} = B(0,1)$. Let us introduce the following propositions,

$P_1$ : $\mathcal{S}$ contains all triangles and if $P = [z_0,\ldots,z_{n - 1}]$ is a polygon that belongs to $\mathcal{S}$ and $z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $Q = [z_0,\ldots,z_n]$ is still a polygon (which is the union of $P$, the triangle $[z_{n - 1},z_n,z_0]$ and the open edge $]z_{n - 1},z_0[$), then $Q \in \mathcal{S}$.

$P_2$ : $\mathcal{S}$ contains all polygons.

$P_3$ : $\mathcal{S}$ contains all open subsets $\Omega$ such that there exists a diffeomorphism $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ that extends to $f : \overline{\Omega} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{D}}$, which is still a diffeomorphism.

$P_4$ : $\mathcal{S}$ contains all non-empty open simply connected domains.

Let us show that for all $0 \leqslant i \leqslant 3$, $P_i \Rightarrow P_{i + 1}$, hence it is sufficient to prove $P_1$ (which I have been unable to prove but seems more reachable than the initial statement) to get the wanted result.

First of all, if $P_3$ is true, let $\Omega$ be non-empty open and simply connected. By Riemman uniformisation theorem, it is diffeomorphic to the disk $\mathbb{D}$. Let $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ a diffeomorphism (that we can choose to be a biholomorphism if $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$). For all $n$, $\Omega_n = B(0,1 - 2^{-n})$ and $f_n = \frac{1}{1 - 2^{-n}}f_{|\Omega_n}$, which is a diffeomorphism $\Omega_n \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ that extends to the border and the extention is a diffeomorphism. By $P_3$, $\Omega_n \in \mathcal{S}$ and for all $n$, $\Omega_n \subset \Omega_{n + 1}$. Therefore, $\mathcal{S}$ contains $\Omega = \bigcup_{n \geqslant 0} \Omega_n$, which proves $P_4$.

Then, assume $P_1$ is true. Let us show by induction on the number $n$ of edges that $\mathcal{S}$ contains all polygons. If is true for $n = 3$ by hypothesis and $\mathcal{S}$ contains all the $n$-gons, let $Q = [z_0,\ldots,z_n]$ be an $n + 1$-gon. Up to permuting the vertices, we can assume that the open segment $]z_{n - 1},z_0[$ is included in $Q$ (it is true for at least one vertex because each polygon admits a triangulation). Let $P = [z_0,\ldots,z_{n - 1}]$ which belongs to $\mathcal{S}$ by induction. By $P_1$, $Q$ also belongs to $\mathcal{S}$, which proves $P_2$.

Now, let us do the hard part : $P_2 \Rightarrow P_3$. Assume $P_2$ and let $\Omega$ be a domain of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f : \overline{\Omega} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ given by the hypothesis of $P_3$. Let for all $m \geqslant 0$, $\alpha : t \mapsto f^{-1}((1 - 2^{-m})e^{2i\pi t})$, which is a loop in $\Omega$ close to the edge. Let $n \geqslant 0$ and for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $z_k = f^{-1}((1 - 2^{-m})e^{2i\pi k/n}) \in \mathrm{Im}(\alpha)$.

$\mathrm{Im}(\alpha)$ is compact and included in the open set $\Omega$ so there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in \mathrm{Im}(\alpha)$, $|x - y| \leqslant \varepsilon \Rightarrow y \in \Omega$. And by Heine theorem, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are uniformly continuous. Therefore, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $(x,y) \in \overline{\Omega}^2$, $|x - y| \leqslant \delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant 2^{-m - 2}$ and there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $(x,y) \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}^2$, $|x - y| \leqslant \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f^{-1}(x) - f^{-1}(y)| \leqslant \min\{\delta_1,\varepsilon\}$.

Choose $n$ such that $|e^{2i\pi/n} - 1| \leqslant \delta_2$. It implies that for all $k$, $|f(z_k) - f(z_{k + 1})| = |e^{2i\pi/n} - 1| \leqslant \delta_2$ so $|z_k - z_{k + 1}| \leqslant \min\{\delta_1,\varepsilon\}$. Therefore, for any point $z$ on the edge $[z_k,z_{k + 1}]$, $|z_k - p| \leqslant |z_k - z_{k + 1}| \leqslant \min\{\delta_1,\varepsilon\}$ thus $p \in \Omega$ and $|f(z_k) - f(p)| \leqslant 2^{-m - 2}$. In particular, $|f(p)| \leqslant |f(z_k)| + 2^{-m - 2} = 1 - 2^{-m} + 2^{-m - 2}$ and $|f(p)| \geqslant |f(z_k)| - 2^{-m - 2} = 1 - 2^{-m} - 2^{-m - 2}$.

As $\gamma$ is smooth ($f$ is a diffeomorphism), up to increasing $n$, we may assume that $[z_0,\ldots,z_{n - 1}]$ defines a polygon $P_m$, that belongs in $\mathcal{S}$ by proposition $P_2$. If $p$ is a point in the edge of $P_m$ and $P_{m + 1}$, we have $|f(p)| \leqslant 1 - 2^{-m} - 2^{-m - 2}$ because $p$ is in the edge of $P_m$ and $|f(p)| \geqslant 1 - 2^{-(m + 1)} + 2^{-(m + 1) - 2} = 1 - 2^{-m - 1} + 2^{-m + 1}$. It implies $1 - 2^{-m - 1} + 2^{-m + 1} \leqslant 1 - 2^{-m} - 2^{-m - 2}$ i.e. $(8 - 2)2^{-m - 2} \leqslant (4 + 1)2^{-m - 2}$, which is a contradiction. It shows that for all $m$, $P_m \subset P_{m + 1}$ hence $\mathcal{S}$ contains $\Omega = \bigcup_{m \geqslant 0} P_m$, which proves $P_3$.

Now the difficulty is to prove $P_1$, for this, I guess we must add progressively disks to the polygon $P$ in order to fill the triangle $[z_{n - 1},z_n,z_0]$ progressively and use the stability of $\mathcal{S}$ under increasing countable union to add the whole triangle, but I don't see how to show it formally.

---

**Edit :** I found a way to prove $P_1$ even if some parts are not $100\%$ rigourous. Let us introduce,

$P_0$ : $\mathcal{S}$ contains all triangles.

We have $P_0 \Rightarrow P_1$. Indeed, if $P$ and $Q$ are polygons like in the statement of $P_1$, let $x_0$ be a point of $]z_{n - 1},z_0[$ and $r_0$ be the largest $r$ such that $B(x_0,r) \subset Q$. Then, let $x_1$ be the only point of $]x_0,z_0[ \cap \partial B(x_0,r_0)$ and $r_1$ the largest $r$ such that $B(x_1,r_1) \subset Q$.

Like this, we build a sequence of elements on $]x_0,z_0[$ that converge toward some $x_\infty \in ]x_0,z_0]$. If $x_\infty \neq z_0$, then it belongs to $Q$ thus it exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x_\infty,\varepsilon) \subset Q$. For $n$ large enough, $x_n \in B\!\left(x_\infty,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)$ so $B\!\left(x_n,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right) \subset B(x_\infty,\varepsilon) \subset Q$ hence $r_n \geqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ which implies that $x_{n + 1}$ is strictly closer from $z_0$ than $x_\infty$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $x_\infty = z_0$.

Let for all $n$, $D_n = B(x_n,r_n)$ and $U_n = \bigcup_{k = 0}^n D_k$. For all $n$, $U_n \cap D_{n + 1}$ is non-empty and connected so by induction, each $U_n$ belongs de $\mathcal{S}$. Thus $U = \bigcup_{n \geqslant 0} U_n = \bigcup_{n \geqslant 0} D_n \in \mathcal{S}$. Similarly, we can build a countable union of open disks on the other side of $x_0$ (toward $z_{n - 1}$ this time) and build an open set $V \in \mathcal{S}$. $U \cap V = B(x_0,r_0)$ is non-empty and connected thus $W = U \cap V \in \mathcal{S}$.

The fact that $x_n \rightarrow z_0$ (and the same argument in the other side) imply that $W$ contains the open edge $]z_{n - 1},z_0[$. Let $T = [z_{n - 1},z_n,z_0]$ that belongs to $\mathcal{S}$ by hypothesis. $W \cap T$, which is the "half" of $W$ is non-empty and connected. Same thing for $P \cap W$, which is the other "half" of $W$. Therefore, $P \cup W$ and $Q = P \cup W \cup T$ are in $\mathcal{S}$. It proves $P_1$.

Now, to prove $P_0$, take a triangle $T_{0,0} = [z_0,z_1,z_2]$ and consider $D_{0,0}$ the disk inside its incircle. $\partial D_{0,0} \cap \partial T_{0,0}$ are three points, one on each edge of the triangle. Let us call them $z_{0,1} \in ]z_0,z_1[$, $z_{1,2} \in ]z_1,z_2[$ and $z_{2,0} \in ]z_2,z_0[$. Let $T_{1,0} = [z_0,z_{0,1},z_{2,0}]$, $T_{1,1} = [z_1,z_{1,2},z_{0,1}]$ and $T_{1,2} = [z_2,z_{2,0},z_{1,2}]$.

Let for all $0 \leqslant i \leqslant 2$, $D_{1,i}$ be the disk inside the incircle of $T_{1,i}$. Clearly, the $D_{0,0} \cap D_{1,i}$ are non-empty, connected and pairwise disjoint thus $U_1 = D_{0,0} \cup D_{1,0} \cup D_{1,1} \cup D_{1,2}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$.

Repeating this operation, we build $U_n \in \mathcal{S}$ that is the union of $\sum_{k = 0}^n 3^k = \frac{3^{n + 1} - 1}{2}$ open disks (it is probably pretty long and hard to check it rigourously by I am pretty sure it works) and $T = \bigcup_{n \geqslant 0} U_n$ (once more, it is absolutely not trivial but intuitively true), thus $T \in \mathcal{S}$, which proves $P_0$.